# Error using VBScript in BGInfo "Variable is undefined: 'WScript'"

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm an amateur VB scripter. I'm making a script to check to see if one of two files exists, and if so, give a flag that says "Installed". If neither file exists, flag "Not Installed". Here is my script...

```
Option Explicit
DIM fso    
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

If (fso.FileExists("C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\KACE\AMPAgent.exe")) OR (fso.FileExists("C:\Program Files\Dell\KACE\AMPAgent.exe")) Then
  WScript.Echo("Installed")
  WScript.Quit()
Else
  WScript.Echo("Not Installed")
  WScript.Quit()

End If
```

It works when I run it in Windows 7. When I add it to BGInfo, it throws up this error...

> Error evaluating scripted field 'KACE'
>
> Microsoft VBScript runtime error
>
> Line 7, position 2
>
> Variable is undefined: 'WScript'
>
> [OK]

I think I just need a way to define or call WScript to action since it's obviously not doing it through BGInfo on its own, and what I did isn't working. I haven't seen anything to help with this particular problem on StackOverflow already.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Would be useful to mention what BGinfo is, for us that don't know. Info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx. Good first post!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I noticed yesterday that I always seem to find my answer on StackOverflow, but I had never joined it. This place is my goto place now. I'm glad my first Q&A go-round went well. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BGInfo implements its own scripting host and doesn't appear to emulate the WScript object.  Browsing [some snippets](http://slingfive.com/pages/code/bgInfo_scripts/) I found on the Internet, it looks like just plain Echo works inside BGInfo.  A snippet:

```
On Error Resume Next
    call WScript.Echo(strReturn)    'for cmd line
    call Echo(strReturn)    'for BGInfo
on error goto 0
```

Note how On Error helps to make it work either way.

Comment: +1. You beat me to it. I just found it in [Mark's article here](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/bginfo) and was writing the same thing.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I also removed the quit lines since they seemed unnecessary, and it tested perfect on every test machine. Thank you very much for your help!